# twitter bootstrap example-blog show active: nav a

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the blog-example of Twitter Bootstrap with a navigation that looks like:

```
<div class="blog-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="blog-nav">
      <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/one">Three</a>
      <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/two">Three</a>
      <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/three">Three</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Idea was to show the active link via query:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav a').click(function (e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $('nav a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
```

But now my links are not clickable anymore. Active tab is showing. 
What to do?

Answer (score 6):

The job of `e.preventDefault` (`event.preventDefault`) is to prevent the default behaviour associated with the element you are listening to.
The default behaviour for an anchor is to navigate somewhere.

Because of this, your links will no longer trigger a page change. Remove the `e.preventDefault()` statement and your links will work again.

You do, however, have a fundamental problem with your idea. JavaScript will not be able to do what you want as navigating to a new page means resetting the page's state.
It's as if your JavaScript was never run :(

Comment: ok, thanks for that. Without e.preventDefault indeed the 'active' shows up while clicking but then disappears.

Answer (score 3):

You're preventing the default action! Are you saying you want to show the page that you are currently on with the "active" class? How about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  $('a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

I do see that you are adding an on-click handler so is it something else?

Comment: Indeed I'd like something like: <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="/one">Three</a>. Thanks for you code.. but unfortunately that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: There was a minor bug, now it says var path

Comment: changed it but no success.

Comment: Adding the class to the active url can use different jQuery depending on your path. There's many, many ideas in the wild. Generally, you'd open up your menu functions in your CMS and if the node is current then you add the class.

Comment: @user1037763 -- also, most scripts will add the class active to the link and not the list item, which is where bootstrap puts it's active css li.active > a, this script is putting the class .active on the link and not the li, so if id does work for your url, you won't see it unless you check your developer tools or equiv. and then put the styles on the a

Comment: thanks for your comments. Looking in the source the .active class just does not appear. The pages are dynamically created while using a single template in which I hoped to create a solution. With the <li> style menu's of Twitter Bootstrap I could work it out but here unsuccessful yet.

Answer (score 1):

okay answering my own question...plain javascript

```
<script>
var filename=$(location).attr('href');
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('nav > a').each(function(){
    var my_list_of_href= $(this).attr('href');
    //console.log(my_list_of_href);

    if (filename.substring(0,my_list_of_href.length)===my_list_of_href){
      $(this).addClass("active");

    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault();` preventing default browser behaviors e.g. clicking urls

Answer (score 0):

Off of dreamriver's answer

```
function activeNav() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  jQuery('a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
}

jQuery(document).ready( function () {
  activeNav();
  jQuery(document).on( 'page:load', function () {
    activeNav();
  });
});
```